# Loading Drop down list from database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to load the Drop down list by fetching the values from the Database .Am using SpringMVC, Hibernate.When the list is fetched from the database.it displays with table name id.
it looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuX1m.png) 
"DeviceType [idDT=1, Devices=Desktop computer]"
instead of only (Desktop computer)

Models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customers implements Serializable

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "DevCustomers",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMERS") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "IDDEV_TYPE") })
    private Set<DeviceType> deviceType = new HashSet<DeviceType>();

public Set<DeviceType> getDeviceType() {
        return deviceType;
    }

    public void setDeviceType(Set<DeviceType> deviceType) {
        this.deviceType = deviceType;

**************************DeviceType************************************

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "DeviceType")
        public class DeviceType implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Integer idDT;

            @Column(name = "DEVICES", length=20, unique=true, nullable=false)
            private String Devices = DeviceTypes.Desktopcomputer.getDeviceTypes();


            public Integer getIdDT() {
                return idDT;
            }

            public void setIdDT(Integer idDT) {
                this.idDT = idDT;
            }

            public String getDevices() {
                return Devices;
            }

            public void setDevices(String devices) {
                Devices = devices;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + ((idDT == null) ? 0 : idDT.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((Devices == null) ? 0 : Devices.hashCode());
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                    return true;
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;
                if (!(obj instanceof DeviceType))
                    return false;
                DeviceType other = (DeviceType) obj;
                if (idDT == null) {
                    if (other.idDT != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!idDT.equals(other.idDT))
                    return false;
                if (Devices == null) {
                    if (other.Devices != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!Devices.equals(other.Devices))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "DeviceType [idDT=" + idDT + ", Devices=" + Devices + "]";
            }
        }

 ************************************************************************
    public enum DeviceTypes implements Serializable {

        Desktopcomputer("Desktop computer"),
        laptop("laptop"),
        Miscellaneous("Miscellaneous"),
        Notebook("Notebook"),
        Server("Server"),
        Smartphone("Smartphone"),
        Tablet("Tablet");

         String deviceTypes;


        private DeviceTypes(String deviceTypes){
            this.deviceTypes = deviceTypes;
        }

        public String getDeviceTypes(){
            return deviceTypes;
        }
    }
```

DAO:

```
 public interface DeviceTypeDao {

        List<DeviceType>findAllCustomers();

        DeviceType findByRType(String deviceType);

        DeviceType findByRId(int idDT);
    }

    ******************************implements**************************************

    @Repository("deviceTypeDao")
    public class DeviceTypeDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, DeviceType> implements DeviceTypeDao {

        static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceTypeDaoImpl.class);


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<DeviceType> findAllCustomers() {
            Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
            crit.addOrder(Order.asc("Devices"));
            return (List<DeviceType>)crit.list();
        }

        @Override
        public DeviceType findByRType(String devices) {
            Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("Devices", devices));
            return (DeviceType) crit.uniqueResult();
        }

        @Override
        public DeviceType findByRId(int idDT) {
            return getByKey(idDT);
        }

    }

Services:

public interface DeviceTypeService {

    List<DeviceType>findAllCustomers();

    DeviceType findByRType(String deviceType);

    DeviceType findByRId(int idDT);

}

*******************implements*****************************

public class DeviceTypeServiceImpl implements DeviceTypeService {

    @Autowired
    DeviceTypeDao deviceDao ;

    @Override
    public List<DeviceType> findAllCustomers() {
        return deviceDao.findAllCustomers();
    }

    @Override
    public DeviceType findByRType(String deviceType) {
        return deviceDao.findByRType(deviceType);
    }

    @Override
    public DeviceType findByRId(int idDT) {
        return deviceDao.findByRId(idDT);
    }

}
```

controller:

```
/**
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new user.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newcustomer" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newcustomer(ModelMap model) {
        Customers customers = new Customers();
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "newcustomer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newcustomer" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomers(@Valid Customers customers, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "newcustomer";
        }

        if (!customersService.isCustomersPhoneUnique(customers.getIdCustomers(), customers.getCustomer_MPhone())) {
            FieldError CustomerPhoneError = new FieldError("customers", "CustomerPhone", messageSource
                    .getMessage("non.unique.CustomerPhone", new String[] {customers.getCustomer_MPhone()  }, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(CustomerPhoneError);
            return "newcustomer";
    }

        customersService.saveCustomers(customers);

          model.addAttribute("Thank you ", "Customer " + customers.getCustomer_Name() + " "+ " registered successfully");
            model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
            return "checkinsuccess";

    }

    /**
     * This method will provide device type list to views
     */
    @ModelAttribute("device")
    public List<DeviceType>initializeDeives(){
        return deviceTypeService.findAllCustomers();
    }
```

Views:

```
 <div class="control-group ">
     <label class="control-label" for="device">Asset/DeviceType</label>
     <div class="controls">
     <form:select path="" id="device" class="form-control span4" >
    <form:option value="" >Select Device</form:option>
    <form:options path="deviceType" items="${device}" />
    </form:select>
    <div class="has-error">
    <form:errors path="deviceType" class="help-inline" />
      </div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

I can not find where the problem is.What is wrong with my codes ?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `list` of `DeviceType` which itself contains properties `id` and `DEVICES` so try as follows,

```
   <div class="control-group ">
         <label class="control-label" for="device">Asset/DeviceType</label>
         <div class="controls">
         <form:select path="" id="device" class="form-control span4" >
        <form:option value="" >Select Device</form:option>
        <form:options path="deviceType" items="${device.DEVICES}" />
        </form:select>
        <div class="has-error">
        <form:errors path="deviceType" class="help-inline" />
          </div>
           </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: it did not work it throws error (org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/newcustomer.jsp at line 221
)
Root cause:
{java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DEVICES"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 
}

Comment: what it throws?

Comment: this Exception:
(org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/newcustomer.jsp at line 221 ) Root cause: {java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DEVICES" java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormat‌​Exception.java:65) java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) }

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.
I added these parameters to the options tags itemLabel="" itemValue=""

```
    <div class="control-group ">
   <label class="control-label" for="device">Asset/Device Type</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <form:select path="" id="device" class="form-control span3">
   <form:option value="">Select Device</form:option>
   <form:options path="deviceTypes" items="${devices} "itemLabel="Devices" itemValue="idDT" />
    </form:select>
  <div class="has-error">
  <form:errors path="deviceTypes" class="help-inline" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```